# Send emails with attachments via c #

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtp, email-attachments

I would like to send an email with attachments via C #, I tried with the following code which is compiled but then once I start the program I receive what is reported in the screenshot and the email is not sent, can anyone help me?

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

static void email_send()
{
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtpservername");
    mail.From = new MailAddress("sendingemail");
    mail.To.Add("emailrecipients");
    mail.Subject = "Test email";
    mail.Body = "mail with attachment";

    System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
    attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment("D:/attachment.txt");
    mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);

    SmtpServer.Port = 25;
    SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("sendingemail", "sendingemailpassword");
    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = false;

    SmtpServer.Send(mail);

}
email_send();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.attachment.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-net-mail-attachment-ctor(system-string)) for how you're creating your attachment, you are just appending the string "D:/attachment.txt" to the email rather than the file itself.

In order to send the file as an attachment, you want to use the [Attachment(Stream stream, string? name)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.attachment.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-net-mail-attachment-ctor(system-io-stream-system-string)) constructor for your attachment.

Before you tried sending the attachment, did you verify that the credentials and SMTP server you have setup all work?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error you're getting it sounds like it's a configuration issue, not an issue with there being an attachment.

Have you tried with `SslEnabled = true`?

To test whether the credentials are the issue, you could try making the request locally using:
`SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = true`

Another thing worth pointing out is that I'd recommend utilising a using block for your SmtpServer variable, as this will handle disposing any resources, especially if you try adding an attachment as a memory stream.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I use. Notice that the `Attatchments.Add` has New Attatchment(filepath) vs just the file path

```
Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient()
    Dim mail As New MailMessage()
    SmtpServer.Credentials = New _
     Net.NetworkCredential("user@emailaddress", "password")
    SmtpServer.Port = 25
    SmtpServer.Host = "mail.mailserver.com"
    mail = New MailMessage()
    mail.From = New MailAddress("user@emailaddress")
    mail.To.Add(_ToEmailAddress)
    mail.Subject = "Data"
    mail.Body = "This email was automatically generated." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf 
  &
        "Please email user@emailaddress if this email was sent to the wrong 
  address."
    mail.Attachments.Add(New Attachment(_FilePath))
    SmtpServer.Send(mail)
Console.WriteLine("Email sent!")
```

Comment: This code is always relative to "using System.Net.Mail;" ?

Comment: Yes. `Imports System.Net.Mail`